# How do I remove visual assets from UWP projects

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I used the asset generator to auto-generate icons for my app, but most of them look very bad. So, I thought to cut down on the number of icons, but now I can't find any option to **remove** an image from the Visual Assets listing. only adding/auto-generating them. Opening the associated `Package.appxmanifest` file doesn't show any of these images being even referenced. And without solving this problem, Visual Studio is not letting me even build the project >_<

[image]

So, I'd like to understand how to remove some of these images? Searching the microsoft forums, but haven't yet found anything related to "removing" assets,

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the path to the file, ie `Assets\SmallTile.png` in `Package.appxmanifest`.

You cannot however remove all the assets since some sizes like splash screen or medium tile are required - you'll have to generate/add new.

Also make sure that these checkboxes are not checked for icons you've removed.

[image: Display Settings]

Answer (score 1):

You need to undo in 3 steps:

Remove the Logo settings from Package.appxmanifest, but leave the required ones.

Open Assets folder, delete all auto-generated assets, again, leave the required ones.

Close your project, and open your .csproj file in notepad, delete the newly added referenced items - they look like below, and then save the csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LargeTile.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SmallTile.scale-150.png" />
    ...
```